# OpenGL Smooth Polygon

Tags: c++, opengl, smoothing, polygons

I am trying to make this a smooth polygon using OpenGL, but it is not doing anything.  Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

```
glColor4ub(r, g, b, a);

glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2i(x, y);
        glVertex2i(x1, y1);
        glVertex2i(x2, y2);
        glVertex2i(x3, y3);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method to smooth rendering is way out of date. It would be better to use multisampling with the [GL_ARB_multisample](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multisample.txt) extension.